# RequestBuilder does not contain a definition for 'Request'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am currently busy creating a `.NET 6.0` application that uses the MS Graph Beta API to collect a bunch of active TI's from the `Security.TiIndicators` endpoint. However something seems to be wrong.

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tiindicators-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp#request) it is stated to use the following code:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var tiIndicators = await graphClient.Security.TiIndicators
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

However, when I try to implement this I get the following error:

`'TiIndicatorsRequestBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Request' and no accessible extension method 'Request' accepting a first argument of type 'TiIndicatorsRequestBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I have the following MS Graph packages installed:

- Microsoft.Graph.Auth | 1.0.0-preview.7
- Microsoft.Graph.Beta | 5.13.0-preview
- Microsoft.Graph.Core | 3.0.0-preview.16

PS. I have more packages but they are not related to MS Graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `beta` SDK you can call directly method `GetAsync()` which returns `TiIndicatorCollectionResponse`.

Collection of `TiIndicator` is accessible through `Value` property.

```
var tiIndicatorsResponse = await graphClient.Security.TiIndicators.GetAsync();
var tiIndicators = tiIndicatorsResponse.Value;
```

Since `Microsoft.Graph.Beta | 5.12.0-preview`, there is a new way how beta models and request builders are generated but it's not yet documented.

Comment: Any idea where it is documented. Cause I also want to use query paramaters.

Comment: Found it: [Link](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#query-options)

Comment: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/feature/5.0/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#removal-of-request-from-the-fluent-api